# Issue in creating a creating a dictionary from a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, dictionary

I have the following string. I am converting it to dictionary but the output I am retrieving is not the expected output.

```
result = ' Thomas got 99 and James got 95, Gerrard got 84 and Tim got 21'

mydict = dict((k.strip(), v.strip()) for k,v in 
          (item.split('and') for item in result.split(',')))
print(mydict)
output is: {'Thomas got 99': 'James got 95', 'Gerrard got 84': 'Tim got 21'}
```

I want the expected output to be like the below

```
 output is:{'Thomas': '99', 'James': '95', 'Gerrard': '84', 'Tim': '21'}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use zip() function to create dict fro two lists

```
import re
result = ' Thomas got 99 and James got 95, Gerrard got 84 and Tim got 21'
key = re.findall('[A-Z]+[a-z]+',result)
value = re.findall(r'\d+',result)
print(dict(zip(key,value)))
#{'Thomas': '99', 'James': '95', 'Gerrard': '84', 'Tim': '21'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Regex.

**Ex:**

```
import re

result = ' Thomas got 99 and James got 95, Gerrard got 84 and Tim got 21'
print(dict(re.findall(r"(\w+) got (\d+)", result)))
```

**Output:**

```
{'Thomas': '99', 'James': '95', 'Gerrard': '84', 'Tim': '21'}
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing and instead of got, and don't have so many "ands" just use commas so do

```
result = ' Thomas got 99, James got 95, Gerrard got 84, Tim got 21'
mydict = dict((k.strip(), v.strip()) for k,v in 
      (item.split('got') for item in result.split(',')))
print(mydict)
```

ran this in my IDE and the result was what you were looking for, hope this helps